# Detective work: Why dropping few rows makes R/glm.nb break down

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm fitting a negative binomial glm to this dataset of 102 records (R code to reproduce below):

```
dat[1:10,]
   n_vsg is_intermediate    size
1      4            TRUE  384417
2      0            TRUE  221292
3      4            TRUE  185133
4      3            TRUE  180336
5      0            TRUE  142391
6      0            TRUE  118786
7      0            TRUE   52865
8      0            TRUE   49724
9    192           FALSE 5080222
10   471           FALSE 4554032

nrow(dat)
[1] 102
```

The fit works and the output looks sensible:

```
library(MASS)

fit <- glm.nb(n_vsg ~ is_intermediate + offset(log(size)), data=dat)

summary(fit)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = n_vsg ~ is_intermediate + offset(log(size)), 
    data = dat, init.theta = 0.3884698627, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8016  -1.4827  -0.4896   0.5715   1.3751  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -9.7409     0.1723 -56.544   <2e-16 ***
is_intermediateTRUE  -2.1419     0.7026  -3.049   0.0023 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.3885) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 116.02  on 101  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 109.18  on 100  degrees of freedom
AIC: 665.35

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.3885 
          Std. Err.:  0.0643 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -659.3460
```

However, if I exclude a few rows things break down. Rows to be excluded:

```
dat[dat$size <= 40000,]
    n_vsg is_intermediate size
96      1           FALSE 8875
97      1           FALSE 6891
98      1           FALSE 5894
99      2           FALSE 4510
100     1           FALSE 4424
101     0           FALSE 3594
102     1           FALSE 2667
```

If I fit the model again I get warnings and a suspicious summary (e.g. the huge `theta` parameter estimate):

```
fit <- glm.nb(n_vsg ~ is_intermediate + offset(log(size)), data=dat[dat$size > 40000,])

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  ... :
  iteration limit reached
2: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced

summary(fit)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = n_vsg ~ is_intermediate + offset(log(size)), 
    data = dat[dat$size > 40000, ], init.theta = 551989.8356, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-18.736   -4.147   -2.736    2.071   12.563  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -9.61483    0.01676 -573.686  < 2e-16 ***
is_intermediateTRUE -2.09168    0.30198   -6.927 4.31e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(551989.8) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2976.1  on 94  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2867.6  on 93  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3152.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1

Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'nsmall' argument
```

Trying to increase the number of iterations makes things even worse as glm.nb throws an error:

```
fit <- glm.nb(n_vsg ~ is_intermediate + offset(log(size)), data=dat[dat$size > 40000,], control=glm.control(maxit=100))
Error in while ((iter <- iter + 1) <= control$maxit && (abs(Lm0 - Lm)/d1 +  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 22 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  ... :
  iteration limit reached
2: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced
```

I'm trying to understand why those 7 rows make such a big difference and whether I should be also worried about the fit using the whole dataset - any ideas?

---

Code to reproduce the dataset:

````
dat <- structure(list(n_vsg = c(4L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 192L, 
471L, 126L, 2L, 195L, 224L, 94L, 92L, 52L, 105L, 255L, 264L, 
9L, 157L, 4L, 131L, 102L, 88L, 117L, 105L, 99L, 98L, 74L, 54L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 78L, 0L, 35L, 1L, 53L, 53L, 50L, 0L, 36L, 5L, 
0L, 4L, 0L, 26L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
13L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 1L, 16L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 0L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L), is_intermediate = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), size = c(384417L, 221292L, 185133L, 180336L, 142391L, 
118786L, 52865L, 49724L, 5080222L, 4554032L, 3276693L, 2796483L, 
2774487L, 2693644L, 2613586L, 2500322L, 2194184L, 2034541L, 1934481L, 
1629173L, 1081040L, 982302L, 899278L, 772487L, 753023L, 683495L, 
679305L, 591882L, 588275L, 538565L, 493678L, 427819L, 427026L, 
424018L, 404648L, 403957L, 396494L, 371527L, 343815L, 322490L, 
314569L, 308237L, 283655L, 271305L, 263027L, 252506L, 234199L, 
233183L, 218780L, 194206L, 186114L, 184070L, 176204L, 174762L, 
169358L, 167134L, 163862L, 152822L, 150071L, 134035L, 130632L, 
130450L, 129439L, 129278L, 128338L, 124382L, 120974L, 119509L, 
117212L, 116240L, 115812L, 110246L, 109329L, 109235L, 107145L, 
105694L, 105417L, 104673L, 104050L, 100895L, 99441L, 95355L, 
93545L, 90484L, 89151L, 88441L, 81933L, 79848L, 78018L, 70042L, 
69156L, 58631L, 54794L, 50565L, 46365L, 8875L, 6891L, 5894L, 
4510L, 4424L, 3594L, 2667L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L))

```
````

Comment: When you remove rows 99 and 100 simultaneously from your data (`dat[-c(100,99),]`), your model generates these errors. Incidentally, you generate some overdispersion when you remove these two rows, which is probably at the origin of the errors you get. (You can test for overdispersion with the library "*performance*", with the function `check_overdispersion(fit)`). If you need to get rid off these rows, maybe ask a separate question on how to deal with overdispersion in a negative binomial model, to get more feedback about this issue.